# How to set alignSelf for flexDirection=row

Tags: javascript, react-native, flexbox

I want to create a `View` as `flexDirection="row"`.
but I cannot use `alignSelf` when I use `flexDirection="row"`.
now, How can I use this figure:

```
|                                                 |
|LeftItem-1  LeftItem-2                  RightItem|
|                                                 |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are using `flexDirection="row"` then alignSelf work vertically. When you are using `flexDirection="column"` then alignSelf work horizontally.

So for that, you have to use `JustifyContent`.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
    <View style={{flexDirection: "row",flex:1}}>
        <Text> LeftItem-1   </Text>
        <Text> LeftItem-2   </Text>
    </View>
    <Text> LeftItem-3   </Text>
</View>
```

This way you can achieve your output.

You can learn more about flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to achieve this. One simple way to achieve the layout you require would be via the following:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection : "row" }}>
    <Text>LeftItem-1</Text>
    <Text>LeftItem-2</Text>
    <View style={{ flex : 1 }}></View>
    <Text>RightItem</Text>
</View>
```

Another option would be to group the left elements in a `<View>` and then use the `space-between` - this would however add extra complexity to your view structure and styling:

```
 <View style={{ flexDirection : "row", justifyContent:"space-between" }}>
    <View style={{ flexDirection : "row" }}>
      <Text>1</Text>
      <Text>2</Text>
    </View>
    <Text>RightItem</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Group left side in one group, and use

```
justify-content:space-between;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you’re using a flexbox with `flexDirection="row"`,

alignSelf, as well as the alignItems property, refers to how items are aligned vertically

If you want to create this exact figure, put your two left items in a div, and use

```
justify-content:space-between;
```

to set the two group far apart horizontally